# Record interactive plot

Tags: matplotlib

The following code works fine to save an animation to file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, bitrate=1800)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ims = []
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi,200)
for theta in np.linspace(0, np.pi, 50):
    plot = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x + theta))
    ims.append(plot)

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True)
im_ani.save('im.mp4', writer=writer)
```

Now, I would like to view the animation interactively as the plots are generated, while still saving it to file. I therefore tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=15, bitrate=1800)

plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ims = []
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 200)
for theta in np.linspace(0, np.pi, 50):
    ax.clear()
    plot = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x + theta))
    ims.append(plot)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True)
im_ani.save('im.mp4', writer=writer)
```

which lets me view the animation interactively, but the resulting video file contains only blank frames.
Is is possible to view an animation interactively and save it to file at the same time? What is the issue with my code?

Comment: The problem is that `ax.clear()` clears the axes and thereby removes all plots from it, such that the saved animation does not contain anything. What is the reason you want to show the animation *while*  it is being created, and not simply show it afterwards (i.e. `plt.show()` at the end of the first code)?

Comment: It's just more user-friendly, makes spotting problems faster, etc. AFAIK, `plt.show()` at the end of the first code would just show the last plot? I thought the problem could be coming from ax.clear(), but I am not aware of any method that 'clears the figure' but keeps the objects in memory.

Comment: Mhh, no, plt.show() at the end of the first code would show the full animation.

Comment: You are correct. But my question remains: with longish animations, immediate feedback is desirable.

Comment: It should be possible to set all but the last artist invisible, `.set_visible(False)`. Then before starting the animation set them all visible again.

Comment: Have you considered drawing two figures, one for "immediate viewing" and one for storing to `mp4`?